# Return a value after disposeing popup jframe

Tags: java, swing, methods, return-value

I am new to Java , I have a main frame  through which I am initializing an other child frame then I want to **return a string value only after child frame disposes**

**Problem areas**

1- Return the value of string to main frame when a particular event is called from child frame.

May be I am not handling setters and getters method properly.

Child class

```
      Private String[] cmd;
      public String[] cmnd (){
       ArrayList<String> vals=new ArrayList<String>();
        vals.add("C:\\");   
      vals.add("--version");   
      cmd= vals.toArray(new String[vals.size()]);            
       return cmd;
      }
```

String value must return after calling this event

```
   private void runActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt){                                    

     cmnd();   /// here i want program to return value
     mcrl2Transform.this.dispose();
}
```

class where  want this string

```
    childframe get=new childframe();
     get.setVisible(true);   
     String[] cmds=get.cmnd();
    if(commands != null){
      for(String s : cmd)
       System.out.println(s);}
```

Comment: You should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help, or at least a clearer example of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: actually event is off private and not return any value- and i can't use it in main as there i have do do some other string operations here using this frame methods .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a callback method to the main-frame class like this:

```
private void runActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt){                                    

 String[] value=cmnd();   /// here i want program to return value
 mainFrame.setCmnd(value);
 mcrl2Transform.this.dispose();
 }
```

or you need ot cache the value in a member variable holding your String[].

Comment: what is this  setCmnd(value) method i don't have any method of this type in mainframe.

the object to child class i called is in a button event as follow.

private void lcpButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
                     
      childframe get=new childframe();
     get.setVisible(true);
  
   String[] cmds=get.Cmd();
     if(commands != null){
         for(String s : cmnd)
         System.out.println(s);}

Comment: Would you please give me some example code to this method which receives sets value in main.